# Log during methodeGUI java

Tags: java, user-interface, logging

I wrote a java program and made a GUI (my first one jeej).

This is my main methode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                ui frame = new ui();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                ui.log("Something went wrong: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

The methode ui.log let's me write to a textArea.

My gui has one button which starts a pretty long methode which takes several minutes to complete. 
In this long methode I want to be able to log to my textArea using ui.log(). 
It works, but It is only displayed when the methode ends and I want to see the results while the methode is running.
Both the button and the buttonEvent listener are made inside new ui();

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("button1");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        thveryLongMethodeThatIwantToLogDuringExecution();
        }
    });
```

Does anyone knows how I can log while the methode is running?

EDIT: I think it has something to do with threads but I'm not sure. I never done something with threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't perform your work on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Use the [javax.swing.SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to run time-consuming background tasks.

Comment: Thank you :D, will have a look